# How to make RAID 1 of system partition win7?

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning

I just made a mirror of my system partition as shown on screenshot, but I don’t know how to mirror reserved 100mb hidden partition:

[image]

I want my system boot normally if I remove one of the hard drives. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you intend to mount the reserved partition? If not you could just copy parts of the disk (including the boot record and that first reserved partition) and just mirror the OS part.  That way you can boot from both disks but only use the two 'c' partitions in a mirrors.

Answer (score 1):

See https://serverfault.com/questions/31812/silly-question-can-i-juste-remove-a-disk-from-a-live-raid1-array

RAID arrays are not meant to be pulled apart. They may survive, but will need to re-sync.

Also, a RAID isn't a 'drive' it's a partition.

Comment: But what if I loose boot disk? how can I re-sync them if 2nd disk don't load windows? I need it "hot-swap" feature with system remain bootable.